# CentOS 7 persistent routing issue?

Tags: centos, route

I have Googled a lot but still can't find a working way on how to make some persistent routes on centOS 7.

```
[root@asd network-scripts]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.23.40.1     0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 enp10s0f1
172.23.40.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp10s0f1


enp10s0f0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
inet6 fe80::226:55ff:fed1:9123  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
ether 00:26:55:d1:91:23  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
RX packets 1096  bytes 291485 (284.6 KiB)
RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
TX packets 12  bytes 2040 (1.9 KiB)
TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
device interrupt 34  memory 0xfbfe0000-fc000000

enp10s0f1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
inet 172.23.40.77  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.23.40.255
inet6 fe80::226:55ff:fed1:9122  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
ether 00:26:55:d1:91:22  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
RX packets 2865  bytes 457736 (447.0 KiB)
RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
TX packets 1995  bytes 345793 (337.6 KiB)
TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
device interrupt 24  memory 0xfbee0000-fbf00000
```

Everywhere I've search on Google it says to configure in the folder below in the file `route-eth0`. But my files are not like that, they are "ifcfg-enp10s0f0". I have this file here: `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   321 Sep 15 13:34 ifcfg-enp10s0f1
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   440 Sep 15 14:44 ifcfg-enp10s0f0
[root@asd network-scripts]#
```

I have tried to add a file like `route-enp10s0f0`. I added the route on `/etc/sysconfig/network` file, but nothing works. Every time I do `service network restart` all disappears!

I have added in `ifcfg-enp10s0f0`:

```
GATEWAY0=0.0.0.0
NETMASK0=255.255.255.0
ADDRESS0=192.168.0.0
GATEWAY1=0.0.0.0
NETMASK1=255.255.0.0
ADDRESS1=169.254.0.0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: device name may vary depending on hardware. If your host insist on the name being enp1s0f1, just keep it. can you `ping`host in 172.23.40.X ? which network you want to use ? (172.X.Y.Z or 192.168.X.Y) ?

Comment: I don't know how to make it work, but you can if you want return to old device names: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/
Though I don't know if this workaround is valid for you.

Answer (score 8):

What you found on Google is correct. You need to create a route-(ifname) file.

The content needs to be like the "ip" command but only the last part. Like this:

```
192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.2.1
```

More information can be found in the [RHEL 7 Networking Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-editing_network_configuration_files#sec-Static-Routes_and_the_Default_Gateway).

Answer (score 4):

I think there'ree tasks you'll need to do in order to get persistent ip routes and rules working:

1. first, create a new routing table for your routes by editing `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`, and adding a line, 'mytable' can be changed to something more suitable, 100 is the priority relative to other tables:

   ```
    100  mytable
   ```
2. next specify the rules and routes required for your interface (e.g. eth1) by creating the files (the rules and routes chosen are examples, change them to suit your setup):

in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/rule-eth1`:

```
    fr10.10.244/32 table myta
    to 10.10.10.244/32 table mytable
```

in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth1`:

```
    dlt via 10.10.10.1 dev eth1 tableable
```

3. finally,nstall and enable the extension to NetworkManager that allows the route and rule files to be read:

   ```
    $ sudo yum installworkger-config-routing-rules`
    $ sudo systemctl start NetworkManager-dispatcher.service`
   ```
4. Then reboot to check that everythas it should be.

Comment: kudos on installation of NetworkManager-config-routing-rules and starting the dispatcher service. It got everything working for me.

Answer (score 3):

Where it says `route-eth0`, think `route-enp10s0f0` or `route-enp10s0f1`.

Essentially, the routing rules in the `route-<interface-name>` file are applied when `<interface-name>` is brought up, and removed when `<interface-name>` is taken down.